# Git: Committing a Bare Repository

Tags: git, git-bare

I am using Egit with Eclipse so I dont know if it is the same with the command line.
I have the possibility to "commit" with a right click the Bare Repository.
What does it imply to commit a bare repository?
Lets say that some modifications have been pushed by a colleague on the bare repository, if the bare repository is still not "committed" I won't be able to fetch the changes until the next commit?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of that commit option you see?